# Basic Logic Gate Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have a question that states: "The output is 1 if and only if the input is 1"
I have to identify what kind if gate this is. I believe it's an OR gate, because whenever you have a single 1 as input, you get a 1 as ouput, am I correct?

Comment: You don't need a logic gate to implement this, you just need a wire. Whenever it is high (1) on one 'side' it will be high on the other 'side'

Comment: the question asks what type of logic gate this represents, not how to implement it

Comment: It is not an OR gate.  An OR gate has two inputs.   The gate you are describing has only one input.   It is called a BUFFER GATE. It works as two INVERTER (NOT) gates in a row.  

http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/buffer-gate/

Comment: @Ramiro: Your comment should be an answer. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an OR gate. An OR gate has two inputs. The gate you are describing has only one input. It is called a BUFFER GATE. It works as two INVERTER (NOT) gates in a row.

http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/buffer-gate